# Python - increase matplotlib figure size with dual x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a chart using matplotlib that uses the twinx() function to display two different plots with different y values:

```
plt.plot(Current_Time[1000:66000],Avg_Duration[1000:66000],color='blue',label="Average Duration of All Parked Cars")
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.ylim(0,50000)
plt.ylabel('Duration in Seconds')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt2=plt.twinx()
#plt2.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt2.plot(Current_Time[1000:66000],Quantity[1000:66000],color='purple',label='Quantity of Cars Parked')
plt2.set_ylabel('Cars Parked')
plt2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The issue I am having is when I try to increase the plot size, it separates the charts. Is there a way to increase the plot size and not split into two charts?

Comment: Non-reproducible code, no picture, what do you expect here? Try ```plt.tight_layout()``` before show.

Comment: @sascha, this code is easily reproducible. Any random list  of values for Current_Time, Avg_Duration, and Quantity will suffice. I have searched the matplotlib documentation to no avail. Just wondering if there is a way to keep two charts overlaid when increasing size?

Comment: Reproducibility on SO: copy question-code, run, observe. Surely not working here. Of course different data will look different and random-lists can be anything, at least some different distributions where some of these are very different from others.

Comment: @Jeff When asking about an error or undesired behaviour it is necessary to provide a [mcve]. While in this case,you thought it was sufficient to replace the lists and guess the imports, in reality it's not. Running the example with added imports and random lists works fine. However you are asking about an undesired behaviour, which (as we need to guess) comes from uncommenting two lines. Doing so throws an error which is different from the result you describe. A lot of people will therefore not further look into the question and you deprive yourself from getting a quick answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sure possible to create twin axes in a figure of any size. One just has to make sure to understand the code one's writing. I.e. don't create a new figure using `figure` and then complain that there is a second figure appearing.

Sticking to the matplotlib state machine interface, a solution could look like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#get data
x=np.arange(40)
y=np.random.rand(len(x))*20000+30000
y2=np.random.rand(len(x))*0.5
#create a figure
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
#plot to first axes
plt.plot(x,y,color='blue',label="label1")
plt.ylim(0,50000)
plt.ylabel('ylabel1')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
#create twin axes
ax2=plt.gca().twinx()
#plot to twin axes
plt.plot(x,y2,color='purple',label='label2')
plt.ylabel('ylabel2')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

Or, if you prefer the matplotlib API:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#get data
x=np.arange(40)
y=np.random.rand(len(x))*20000+30000
y2=np.random.rand(len(x))*0.5
#create a figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#plot to first axes
ax.plot(x,y,color='blue',label="label1")
ax.set_ylim(0,50000)
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel1')
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(),rotation=90)
#create twin axes
ax2=ax.twinx()
#plot to twin axes
ax2.plot(x,y2,color='purple',label='label2')
ax2.set_ylabel('ylabel2')

h1, l1 = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=h1+h2, labels=l1+l2, loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```